# Capitalize the last letter of each word in a string

Tags: python-3.x

```
def headAndFoot(s):
    """precondition:  s is a string containing lower-case words and spaces
    The string s contains no non-alpha characters.
    postcondition:  For each word, capitalize the first and last letter.
    If a word is one letter, just capitalize it.  """
    last = len(s) - 1
    x = s.title()
    y = x.split()
    return y
```

What changes do I need to make?

Comment: Why are you splitting the string? And how come you didn't preview the question to make sure that people could read it?

Comment: You need to show some more effort, can you maybe explain how you intended to do it and why you think it should work? Then we could help you understand your mistakes and guide you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my code below and try to use it in the context of your question.

```
s = 'The dog crossed the street'

result = " ".join([x[:-1].title()+x[len(x)-1].upper() for x in s.split()])
```

Then result will look like

```
'ThE DoG CrosseD ThE StreeT'
```

Comment: `x[len(x)-1]` can become `x[-1]`, jfyi

Answer (score -1):

import java.io.*;

public class ConverT_CapS

{

```
void main()throws IOException

{

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Enter a sentence ");

    String str = br.readLine();

    str= str.toLowerCase();

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(str);

    for(int i=1;i<str.length()-1;i++)
    {
        if(str.charAt(i+1)==' '||str.charAt(i-1)==' ')
        {
            char ch= (char)(str.charAt(i)-32);
            sb.setCharAt(i,ch);
        }
    }
    sb.setCharAt(0,(char)(str.charAt(0)-32));
    sb.setCharAt(str.length()-1,(char)(str.charAt(str.length()-1)-32));
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

}

input : whats ur name
output: WhatS UR NamE